# CocoaPods ignoring minimum deployment target (IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET) in post_install hook

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I keep getting the following error from multiple pods when building my react native project in xcode. Some example pods include `RNKeychain` and `RNSVG`. Here’s an example from `react-native-blur`:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTViewManager", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_BlurViewManager in BlurViewManager.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_VibrancyViewManager in VibrancyViewManager.o
```

I noticed some warnings about iOS versions such as `'UIBlurEffectStyleSystemChromeMaterial' is only available on iOS 13.0 or newer`.

Digging into xcode, for some reason the "General -> Deployment Info" for each pod is set to `iOS 11.0` but in my Podfile I have explicitly set the deployment target to `platform :ios, '13.0'`. It's widely accepted as the solution to add a `post_install` script to overwrite the deployment target of each individual pod, which I've done. See my Podfile below.

```
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Foo' do
  use_frameworks!
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  target 'FooTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
    
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

I can fix the issue by manually adjusting the deployment target in xcode for each offending pod which complains with the error `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:`

[image]

What else could be overwriting the deployment info to `ios 11.0`? In case it's relevant using `"react-native": "0.66.1",`

The most infuriating thing is that every time I do `pod install` I have to manually tweak deployment info for each affected pod.